# Create Project/solution in an existing directory?

Tags: visual-studio, ide, visual-studio-2005, visual-sourcesafe

How can I create a New project & Solution in the same, existing , directory?  No matter what I do, it keeps creating a new (sub)directory for the project and populating that directory instead of the one(s) that already exist.  I have the "Create directory for Solution" checkbox cleared so that it will put the solution an dproject in the same folder and not create a solution folder, but it still keeps making the project sub-folder.

How can I fix this?!?

This has bugged me for a long time, but I've been able to ignore it or work-around it up until now.  But now it is kicking my butt productivity-wise on my customer project and I need to fix it.  thanx... RBarryYoung

(Note: This is VS2005, Team Edition for Software Developers)

Comment: Do you want the solution at the root and sub-directories for each project or do you want the solution and project files all in the same directory?

Comment: I assume your work-around has been to simply copy the newly-created project to the directory where you want it? That's how I usually do it, and new projects are added rarely enough for that to work for me.

Comment: James: in this case, all in one directory.

Comment: Fredrik: Yes.  However on this project I have many dozens of projects to make.  The code is all done (did it in one big project), but now I have to reorganize them into 40-50 small projects.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

From Visual Studio, if you have no solution open, you can select

File->New->Project From Existing Code

Select the project type

Put the directory you want the solution and project file to be in as the "Project file location" field.

Finish the wizard and you'll have a project file and solution file in the same directory.

**If the "Project from existing code" option is not available**

Make a custom keyboard shortcut, toolbar button or menu item by using the customization features of VS.

Tools->Customize

Select the "Keyboard" button to add a keyboard shortcut or select the "Command" tab to add a toolbar button or menu item.  The command you are looking for is:

File->New Project From Existing Code

Assign whatever keyboard shortcut or drag an icon to whichever menu/toolbar you want.

Comment: I cannot find this option.  I have File->New Project... which opens the New Project dialog, no "Project From Existing Code" option.  ??

Comment: I am using Professional not Team, but after a bit of testing I see that the option is only available when I'm using the General, C# or C++ Development settings, when VS is configured to use VB or Web Development settings the option is not available.  This can be changed by going to Tools->Import and Export Settings, and selecting Reset.  It will give you the option to backup your current settings, then allow you to select a new profile.

Comment: Another option if you don't want to change your development settings you can customize your environment with a keyboard shortcut or custom menu item or toolbar button:

Tools->Customize

The command you're looking for is File.NewProjectFromExistingCode

I hope this works for you

Comment: (huh, For some reason, I didn't get notified of your comments?)  Could you edit your original answer to add in your additional information?  Thanks, I will try these this afternoon

Comment: This works to add one project but not to put several project files into the same directory as the solution. Maybe doing that isn't a great idea. The purpose I am trying to achieve is simply allow me to build the same projects with different versions of Visual Studio.

Comment: Doesn't display the project type for SSIS projects.

Comment: What if you don't want your project and solution in the same folder, or if you want to build a project from a template? The solution in this answer seems to lack features. I want the same functionality as when I create a new solution normally, I just want the solution to go in an existing folder because I cloned an empty Git repo

Answer (score 13):

To create a solution in an existing directory, I have found the best way is to create it one directory back from where you actually want it, then use the name of the directory where you really want it as the name of the solution.

If that isn't the name you want (i.e. you don't want your solution name to match the name of the directory it is in) then once you have created it, you can rename the solution by right-clicking on it and choosing "Rename". It does not rename the directory it is in nor move it. That is by far the simplest way.

You can obviously use the same trick for a project too, however if you have more than one project in a single directory, ideally the intermediate directory into which they build should differ, otherwise you are going to have issues if you want to rebuild just one of them and it clears out the intermediate target directory.

Answer (score 1):

You can always move things around manually and edit sln file to fix the project references. For example, if you want your solution file to be in the same directory as the project file, you can cut the solution file from wherever it is and paste it into the project file directory. Then you need to edit the solution file to fix the project reference so that the solution can find the project when it is opened.

Comment: This is what I hav edone when I needed to in the past.  However it is slow and error-prone.  Combined with the VSS integration issues (not included here), the anemic PC & network access, it is taking me 3-4 hours per project(!).  I need something more direct and fool-proof.

Comment: How often do you need to move projects around or add new ones that need to fit your organizational requirements? Not too often I hope. 3-4 hours per project means that there must be other things going. Merely moving the solution file, updating project references within it, and then opening the solution file in VS to check if projects load alright should not take that long.

Comment: For this project I have 40-50 to complete.  It thought it should take no more than an hour, but... There's mistakes in the solutions file, mistakes editing the project file, VSS files & interference with both,  some name changes in the code (30 min), moving everything around and getting all into VSS right.  Plus the network connection and shares access is very slow. I need it to make it right the first time.

Comment: (re: I thought it would take an hour each).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any out-of-the-box solutions for you. But, if the code files are organized into folders according to the wanted structure you could hack together a tool to do it for you, perhaps. The project files are not awfully complex in their structure, they are rather straight-forward XML documents, largely consisting of a list of the files that are included in the project.

I would assume that the resulting project files may still require some manual labour, but you should be able to get the code to do the heavy work for you. And you may get a nifty tool to post on your blog.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I pulled a project from repository and wanted to add a solution in this empty directory.
I just create a solution in another path using the same directory name and then copy all the elements into that empty directory, it seems to work.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

1. Open an existing project. If you don't have one yet, create a temporary one.
2. Select "File" > "new" > "Project"
3. Make sure "Create new Solution" is selected
4. Choose the type of project you want.
5. Press Ok to create the project

If you created a temporary project in step one, you can delete it now

-> now you have created a project where the solution file is within the project
[image]

Answer (score -3):

```
            public static class SlnFileGenerator
            {
                #region Public Methods
                public static string GetBatFileContent(string directoryPath, string slnFileName)
                {
                    if (directoryPath == null)
                    {
                        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(directoryPath));
                    }

                    if (slnFileName == null)
                    {
                        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(slnFileName));
                    }

                    var sb = new StringBuilder();
                    sb.AppendLine($"dotnet new sln --name {slnFileName}");

                    foreach (var csprojFile in Directory.GetFiles(directoryPath, "*.csproj", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
                    {
                        var relativePath = csprojFile.RemoveFromStart(directoryPath);

                        sb.AppendLine($"dotnet sln \"{slnFileName}.sln\" add \"{relativePath}\"");
                    }

                    sb.AppendLine("pause");

                    return sb.ToString();
                }
                #endregion
            }
```

Comment: Could you explain in a few words what this code does and how it solves the problem at hand?

Comment: There is absolutely no solution here.. just a code dump

Answer (score -3):

the easiest way to achieve that is using Visual Studio Code extension vscode-solution-explorer

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fernandoescolar.vscode-solution-explorer

In the folder you want to create the .sln file, use the "Create new empty solution" command from the extension.

Then go to the extension's (Solution) tab in VS Code and at the top right-click the name of the solution you created and click on "Add existing project". Navigate to the .csproj file of that project and that's it. A .sln file prepared to be opened in Visual Studio 2022 with Intellisense and stuff.

If you want to add more projects to the solution, same procedure as the step above. Soooooo easy. Hope it helps.

Comment: This question is about Visual Studio, not Visual Studio Code, which despite the similar name is a completely different product.

Comment: @RBarryYoung you are right. That being said, I just wanted to help the OP so he could merge several .csproj project files in a .sln solution file, to work with Visual Studio (VS Code dont load .sln files per se, without extensions nor it works like Visual Studio as an IDE when it comes to C#). Cheers!