# c++ how do you open folder as a project in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio

I have a folder which is a c++ project but it's not a visual studio project.

How can I open the folder as a project or convert it into a visual studio project, so that I can `make` it?

There's no `vcproj` or `sln` files, which is expected. I'm familiar with Visual Studio and would like to take advantage of that environment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Import Existing C++ Source Code into Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853550/import-existing-c-source-code-into-visual-studio)

Comment: You need to create a new project and add the source files to it. However, see if this answer helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923461/create-project-solution-in-an-existing-directory

Comment: Answer 2 here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314553/how-to-use-makefiles-in-visual-studio BUT!!! You will almost certainly have to either  add GCC support to Visual Studio in order to use Visual Studio or replace all of the GCC-isms with their matching MSVC-isms. By the time you are done that and gotten it working, you might as well have gone through the hell of building a Visual studio project by hand. (I call it hell because I know what Asker is trying to port. It's a large and sickeningly complex project)

Answer (score 1):

Only latest Visual Studio release (like 2017) supports such a feature (solution-less Solution Explorer),

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/develop-code-in-visual-studio-without-projects-or-solutions

But if you need debugging or other IDE features, it might not come without a solution. (You should try Visual Studio Code, plus its C++ extension, which should work better in the solution-less scenarios).