How to build VB.net local website in VS 2019 community
I have a very old website developed with VB.NET (.NET framework 2.0) on Microsoft web developer freeware IDE which was obsolete and not available any more. The VB.net website does not have project file as a present VS 2019 normally has. Here is the VS 2019 after VB.net website is opened as a local folder.

In the web.config file opened, the login.aspx was added as start page. However there is no Build menu available in VS2019 and I can not start debug (F5) as well. I guess there must be something missing as I rebuilt the website in VS2019 sometime ago. How to build local website in VS2019 opened from local folder?

What's in the My Project folder?

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/923484/11683. The project type is likely WebForms.

How are you opening this project? Assuming you have the whole web site in a folder on your development computer, then try file->open web site, and select that folder. At that point, you should see or have a build option, and you should be able to hit f5 to test and run.

All right, there is option of website in file->open!
